# Upload files on multiple server (S3, Dropbox, ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm designing a little application using Rails and I need to upload files. I searched and I found paperclip + Carrierwave to do that. I've also seen that it's possible for that gems to specify where to store the uploaded file in the model.

My question is : Using Paperclip, is it possible to know at runtime where the user wants to upload the file and of course is it possible to catch and save the file to the corresponding host ?

Regards

Comment: you mean that the user can choose his own dropbox or s3 instance?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. But you can set up e.g. Amazon S3 and paperclip will upload all the files there..

Comment: I meant I would like that the user can specify where he wants the file is uploaded (i.e a combobox with Dropbox, Amazon S3, ...). Then the file will be uploaded on the remove choosen by the user. Notice that there is only one dropbox, amazon S3, ... account : the application one, I don't want that each user can upload file on their own dropbow. Is it more clear ?